# UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) from webhost

Tags: android

I'm getting my image from my webhost. But my listview is not showing my image that is uploaded even the correct path is on the database.

### Error

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [carkila.esy.es/upload/20160727155302300500.jpeg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [carkila.esy.es/upload/20160727155302300500.jpeg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is how I upload the picture to my webhost

## upload

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(1024,1024).getBitmap();
        String encodeImage = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
        Log.d(TAG, encodeImage);
        HashMap<String,String> post = new HashMap<String,String>();
        post.put("image",encodeImage);
        PostResponseAsyncTask taskUpload = new PostResponseAsyncTask(InsertActivity.this, post, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                if(s.contains("upload_success")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Upload Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Uploading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        taskUpload.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/upload1.php");
```

And this is how I print it on my Listview.

### listview

```
dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return product.Image;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used
            
        }
    });
```

Thanks guy

Comment: it seems that your image is not right

Comment: @tpA - How's the image not right sir? Just a beginner here sir. Hehe.

Comment: @tpA - Should i change this `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView);` ?

Comment: This means that url of your image is not loading